# How to enable/disable Navigation Menu Element in JSP according to date in Mysql?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

I have a JSP file which contains navigation menu and there are several list items. I want to retrieve a date value from Mysql table and compare it with current date. If the current date is before the date that comes from mysql, i want to enable the certain list item("Suggest a project" to direct the user to another jsp. If not, don't direct to anywhere.

I've tried to pass the mysql date to a class and then pass it to javascript.

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>

            <li><a>Suggestion</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:choose();">Suggest A Project</a>
             </ul>
             </li>
            <li><a>Reports</a></li>
            <li><a>Meetings</a></li>
            <li><a>Exams</a></li>
            <li><a>Account Settings</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a>Change Password</a>
            </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
</div>  
    <script>
function choose() { 
   var d=new Date();
   var t = new webtest.servlet.Mysqldate();
   var s=t.SuggestDate(); //get the date from mysql and return it.
    if(d.getTime()>=s.getTime()){
        window.navigate("ogrencikendioner.jsp");
    }
    else{   
        alert("Too late ! Deadline for suggestions is over. ");
    }
}
</script>
```

It's not working. i'm open to any suggestion/option to solve my problem. thanks